# Add BCC to Woocoomerce transactional email sent through Sendinblue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, bcc, sendinblue

We are currently using Sendinblue as mail marketing provider and did set it up on our Wordpress/Woocommerce shop to handle marketing and transactional emails now.

Before that, we used to send some transactional woocommerce transactional email, such as order_completed in bcc to one of our own email addresses. This is necessary for certain internal processes.

Hence Sendinblue has taken over, this function isn't being triggered, or more like is triggered but doesn't get processed through Sendinblue anymore.

Although, I found an API call that could actually do exactly that: https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#sendtransacemail

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"bcc\":[{\"email\":\"something@domain.com\"}]}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

As well as this: https://apidocs.sendinblue.com/tutorial-sending-transactional-email/

Though, I'm absolutely unsure where to add this in order to trigger BCC through Sendinblue.

Would be amazing, if someone could point me in the right direction.

Kind Regards
Chris

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use the API calls to be able to use Sendinblue for Email. What you should do is just making Sendinblue as your Email Server by entering your Sendinblue server details as your Wordpress default SMTP server. You can use the following code to do so.

If you do the above your website will function normally and all triggers will work just fine, the only thing if that your website will use Sendinblue as it's Email Server and all the sent emails will be logged to your  Sendinblue account.

1. How to get your Sendinblue SMTP account working:
   https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/209463245--How-can-I-get-my-SendinBlue-SMTP-account-activated-
2. Very simple article to help you with configuring your SMTP:
   https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215526937-Configuring-the-WP-Mail-SMTP-plugin

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Mohamed.

Actually that didn't work either, since it basically does exactly the same as the Sedinblue WooCommerce plugin does. I guess that both are simply not designed to actually pass the BCC variable.

What did the trick though somehow, after several tries is this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/cc-bcc-for-woocommerce-order-emails/

I have no idea what it does differently, but it works and that is all that matters.